# How to pass in argv for each parse options using optionparse

Tags: ruby

I would like to have some flexibility in parse the options.

```
For example:
if I run this
>  ruby some.rb -t 1
>  outputs: 1
>  ruby some.rb -t 2
>  outputs: 2
>  ruby some.rb -y 1
>  outputs: 3
>  ruby some.rb -y 2
>  outputs: 4
>  ruby some.rb -t 1 -y 2
>  outputs: 5
>  ruby some.rb -y 2 -t 1
>  outputs 5
>  ruby some.rb -t 1 -y 1
>  outputs: 4
```

So What I want to achieve is to have the ability to say

```
ruby some.rb -t=foo -y=bar
```

Comment: Did you research? There are multiple ways to pass options into a script. What did you try? Why didn't it work? If you didn't try, why not? Did you search? If so, where and why didn't those pages help? Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Comment: Please be more patient. Yes I did the research. I went to read the ruby doc 2.4.0 file. But the doc did not explain in a way I could understand. There ARE a lot of examples around of course. I tried a few. None of those I tried satisfied my need. So I ask. Please create an environment that people are more encouraged to ask questions instead of asking around the integrity of asking questions itself. @theTinMan

Comment: This is a great environment to ask questions, however it's important to understand the goals and scope of Stack Overflow. Think of it as an online reference book of programming problems and their solutions. It's not a replacement for your own research and effort, it's to help as a last resort after you've exhausted yourself. Then, at that point, we expect a well detailed question explaining what you tried and why it doesn't solve the problem. Your question doesn't do that, instead you've give requirements for code. Again, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 explains this.

Comment: So, _what research_ did you do? _What code_ did you write and why didn't it work? Your question is the beginning of an article to help others, not just yourself, so you have to explain those things to help those who are searching for a solution for the same thing in the future. The "Related" section to the right shows similar questions, so searching on SO would have returned similar results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is how to parse options, you can use standard [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) like this:

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on("-t T", "arg t") do |t|
    options[:t] = t
  end

  opts.on("-y Y", "arg y") do |y|
    options[:y] = y
  end
end.parse!

p options

###

ruby temp.rb -t 1 -y 2
{:t=>"1", :y=>"2"}
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess that is what I am missing. I did read the doc as in Ruby 2.4.0. But I did not understand it in a correct way.